# Combining Records On Secondary Grouping

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table of speed limits, road numbers, and road segments.  Each road may have multiple segments within a speed limit segment (same road number, same speed limit, different bmp and emp segments). Each road may change speed limit (same road, different speed limit, starts a new bmp).  I need to group the roads by speed limit, but collapse any segments of the same road into 1 unit where the speed limit is the same.  In the following return, for example, records 2 and 3 should be collapsed into 1 record, because the road has the same speed limit, even though that speed limit crosses multiple segments (0.0 - 10.5).
Sorry:  The bmp and emp are "Beginning Mile Post" and "End Mile Post" and separate the road into the afore mentioned segments.

```
           Limit     RoadNum    bmp     emp
     1     25        10001      9.06    16.90
     2     25        09002      0.00     9.39
     3     25        09002      9.20    10.50
     4     25        08003      0.00     3.10
```

The output should look like this (where rec 2 has its original bmp, but the emp of rec 3)  Note: record number 1...4 is not a key or even part of the table.

```
           Limit     RoadNum    bmp     emp
     1     25        10001      9.06    16.90
     2     25        09002      0.00    10.50
     4     25        08003      0.00     3.10
```

This is the simple select statement I used to produce the grouping:

```
select Limit, RoadNum, BMP, EMP
from SpeedLimits
group by Limit, RoadNum, BMP, EMP
order by Limit asc
```

Comment: What columns do you expect to see in the output?

Comment: 1, 2-3 (bmp 0.0 to emp 10.5), 4.  (so 2 and 3 are combine with the bmp of 2 and the emp of 3.
I'm fumbling around with splitting the table by giving it 2 aliases (one for bmp and one for emp)

Comment: please update your question to show the expected output (in text format)

Comment: What does `bmp` stand for?  What does `emp` stand for?  Some context about those columns may be helpful.  Please include these details in your updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you need is to `GROUP BY` `Limit` and `RoadNum` and find `MIN(BMP)` and `MAX(EMP)`

```
select Limit, RoadNum, BMP = MIN(BMP), EMP = MAX(EMP)
from   SpeedLimits
group by Limit, RoadNum
order by Limit asc
```

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Thank you.  Unfortunately, Rec 2 ends up with its original EMP.   It doesn't seem to combine records 2 and 3 (so that 2 has the EMP of 3)
But that might come in handy as I wrestle with this.

Comment: you must have use `MIN()` on `EMP`

Comment: OMG! I did.  I'm so sorry.  My brain is going to mush, I think.
That looks like it did it.
Thank you...Thank you.